# Node Simple Object Factory Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, factory, mqtt

So I have a node application that makes use of [MQTT](https://github.com/adamvr/MQTT.js/).  I want to encapsulate all my MQTT client creation logic in a single place to ease refactoring. I wrote a moudel that looks like the following:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
, host = 'localhost'
, port = '1883';

var settings = {
    keepalive: 30000,
    protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
    protocolVersion: 3,
    username:'testuser',
    password:'testpass'
}

exports.createClient = function(clientId){
    if(clientId){
        settings.clientId = clientId;
    }//otherwise default

    return mqtt.createClient(port, host, settings);
}
```

I'm pretty new to node and would say I have intermediate javascript programming skills.  For whatever reason, whenever I run this code with multiple client creation, all hell breaks loose.   They don't play nice and kick each others connections.

However, If I put the exact same code directly in each file, there are no issue.  One of the more experienced node developers on the team said that it might be something with the way node caches user modules?  That the code actually does not return a new client instance whenever create client is called multiple times.

How can I rewrite this simple factory to function correctly?

Comment: Where does `deviceId` come from?

Comment: Should we clone settings variable, how can you call createClient with single port?

Comment: @vkurchatkin A different module. I removed anything that was non-essential to the code and missed that bit.  I'll edit it away

Comment: @damphat I think the settings as defined outside the function will stay consistent across each device.  However, as you can see where I pass clientId in, other properties could be attached to the object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you share `settings`, but also modify them on each call. This can help:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
, host = 'localhost'
, port = '1883';

exports.createClient = function(clientId){
    var settings = {
        keepalive: 30000,
        protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
        protocolVersion: 3,
        username:'testuser',
        password:'testpass'
    }

    if(clientId){
        settings.clientId = deviceId + '-' + clientId;
    }

    return mqtt.createClient(port, host, settings);
}
```

Also you need to get `deviceId` from arguments or some other legit place

Comment: Ah, now I see it.  Good spot.

Comment: ahh makes perfect sense.  Sorry the device Id is a artifact from reducing my code to its simplest form.

Answer (score 0):

```
// requires up here
module.exports = function (options) {
   var settings = {
       keepalive: options.keepalive,
       protocolId: options.protocolId,
       protocolVersion: options.protocolVersion,
       username: options.username,
       password: options.password
   };

   return {
       createClient: function (clientID) {
           // your client creation code
       },
       otherMethod: function () {...}

   }
}
```

See how it all gets wrapped up?  When you require this module, you will be getting a function back (an object still of course), example:

```
var yourMod = require('./yourMod') ({
    keepalive: 30000,
    protocolId: 'MQIsdp',
    protocolVersion: 3,
    username:'testuser',
    password:'testpass'
});

var cliendID = yourMod.createClient ( 23 );
```

I believe that should work.  I have a tracking module that 3 different apps use, and they all connect to different databases.  This is the basic module layout I use for it.  It's in fact called the module pattern in javascript.

EDIT: Fixed for addressed question.

Comment: That's not going to work. Firstly, a typo - `export`, secondly `var youMod = require('./yourMod')();` instead of what you have.

Comment: The typo is obvious, the second one is not

Comment: Well whatever, fixed.

Comment: Yeah, cool. Also, if you do `var yourMod = require('./yourMod') (); var one = yourMod.createClient(1); var two = yourMod.createClient(2)` The problem remains

Comment: Fixed to address the issue.  Now all settings are local, and passed to the object when required.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but vkurchatkin answer fits better into my current solution. Also having to configure the settings each time I require the module is not ideal.

Comment: Yeah, he nailed it.  But still, it's good to know the module pattern when working in node.